# Symfony2 uniqueEntity validation of multiple fields doesn't work with SonataAdminBundle

Tags: validation, symfony, sonata-admin

I was trying to use the SonataAdminBundle, but the @UniqueEntity Annotation doesn't work.

This is my entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\FooRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"name", "public", "user"},
 *     errorPath="name",
 *     message="This name is already in use."
 * )
 *
 */
class Foo
{
    //...
}
```

The uniqueEntity validation in my Frontend works properly! However SonataAdmin ignores the Annoation.

I tried this:

[assert unique validation in sonata admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086287/assert-unique-validation-in-sonata-admin)

But it also does not work.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to enable as well [cascade validation](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#cascade-validation) in the sonata admin ?

```
class FooAdmin extends Admin  
{    
    protected $formOptions = array(
        'cascade_validation' => true        
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The user must be set before validation! I have injected the security.token_storage service and overwritten the `getNewInstance` function in my class Admin.

#### service.yml

```
sonata.admin.foo:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\FooAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Foo" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - AppBundle\Entity\Foo
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTranslationDomain, [AppBundle] ]
        - [ setSecurityTokenStorage, [@security.token_storage] ]
```

#### FooAdmin

```
class FooAdmin extends Admin
{
    /**
     * @var UserInterface
     */
    private $user;

    public function setSecurityTokenStorage(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $token = $tokenStorage->getToken();

        if (null !== $token) {
            $user = $token->getUser();

            if (is_object($user) && $user instanceof UserInterface) {
                $this->user = $user;
            } else {
                throw new \Exception();
            }
        }
    }

    public function getNewInstance()
    {
        $object = new Foo();
        $object->setUser($this->user);

        return $object;
    }

    // ...
}
```